# Add incremental property to nodes in a chain of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a chain of nodes and I want to add a property `"DtaID"` to each of that nodes and the value should increment during the chain. Is there a way to do this with Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose that you have a chain of nodes in this format:

```
create (:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)-[:LINK]->(:Node)
```

Then I used this Cypher:

```
// Get the path between the start and end nodes, including both
MATCH p = (start:Node)-[:LINK*]->(end:Node)
WHERE NOT (end)-[:LINK]->() AND NOT ()-[:LINK]->(start)
// extract the nodes of p and calc an array of indexes to 
// access each node in the array of nodes called `nodes`.
WITH nodes(p) as nodes, range(0, size(nodes(p))) AS indexes
// unwind indexes as index...
UNWIND indexes AS index
// set the value of `DtaID` property of each nodes to the index value.
// That is: the node 0 will have `DtaID` equal to 0.
// I'm assuming that you need an increment by one. If you need a
// different increment you can do calculations here. For example:
// SET (nodes[index]).DtaID = index * 10 to increment by 10.
SET (nodes[index]).DtaID = index
```

As result:

```
╒═══════════╕
│"n"        │
╞═══════════╡
│{"DtaID":0}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":1}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":2}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":3}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":4}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":5}│
├───────────┤
│{"DtaID":6}│
└───────────┘
```

If you need to use the value of `DtaID` of the first node as a base value, you can pass the first node to the `WITH` clause and use in the calculations.

```
MATCH p = (start:Node)-[:LINK*]->(end:Node)
WHERE NOT (end)-[:LINK]->() AND NOT ()-[:LINK]->(start)
WITH start, nodes(p) as nodes, range(0, size(nodes(p))) AS indexes
UNWIND indexes AS index
SET (nodes[index]).DtaID = start.DtaID + index
```

Comment: works perfect for me. Thank you very much and best regards, Andreas

Comment: @AndreasKuczera Hi! You are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, didn't know this.
Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: @AndreasKuczera you are welcome, Andreas! I suggest to you to [take a tour in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better know StackOverflow.